# exclude one character with regular expression

Tags: regex

I have below string:

```
25Oct2016:102931
```

I want to exclude: from the middle of the string and give me a final string as below in a single group:

```
25Oct2016102931
```

this is my regex:

```
(\d+\w+\d+[^:]\d*)
```

but it doesnt work.
What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot capture discontinuous text into a single group. Either use 2 groups, or use a replacing approach.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Are you aware that `\d` is included in `\w`?

Answer (score 0):

As Wiktor said you cannot capture it in one group, if you want to have 2 groups you could use something like:

```
[^:]+
```

Example:
http://regexr.com/3f30l

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+):([0-9]+)
```

Then for your replacement you can use the 2 capture groups. Either \1\2 or $1$2 depending on what language/software you're using.